# Bite force of seagulls

Tags: ornithology

I'd like to know whether the biggest seagulls are strong enough to bite off a finger?

Comment: There's this [news report](https://empirenews.net/seagull-bites-off-mans-finger-after-eating-bag-of-cheetos/) but I have no idea if it's reliable ...

Comment: "Bite Force of Seagulls" sounds like next year's Oscar-contender movie title

Answer (score 3):

[This reference](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23314498/) states the force needed to fracture a finger was 467 N{1}. The Galapagos finch has a strong beak in the bird world, only 70 N{2}. Most animals that will take your limbs will both have sharp objects and are strong enough to hang on to use body weight to take the limbs. So it is unlikely to be able to rip off your finger, but if you have significant disease and are weak, it might be a good idea to hide your chips.

References:

1. Hohendorff B, Weidermann C, Pollinger P, Burkhart KJ, Müller LP. Jamming of fingers: an experimental study to determine force and deflection in participants and human cadaver specimens for development of a new bionic test device for validation of power-operated motor vehicle side door windows. Biomed Tech (Berl). 2013 Feb;58(1):39-49. doi: https://doi.org/10.1515/bmt-2012-0004. PMID: 23314498. Deutsche Nationalbibliothek full text pdf link [here](https://d-nb.info/1194176852/34).
2. Sakamoto, M., Ruta, M., Venditti, C. (2019); ‘Extreme and rapid bursts of functional adaptations shape bite force in amniotes’; Proceedings B; doi: https://doi.org/10.1098/rspb.2018.1932

Comment: The large ground finch is a ~40g bird with a bill adapted for crushing, compared to the largest seagulls (the Great Black-Backed Gull) at ~2kg, with sharp hooked bills. Removing a finger is a different biomechanical process to fracturing a finger (fracturing requires breaking bone; removing can be done by cutting between bones, which can be much easier if you have a sharp cutting edge). I don't think this answer provides details that are relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: Lowest force in first reference Table 3 is 291 N (specimen 12, MP, little finger) - still way above 70 N though.

Comment: The great mcaw has one of the strongest bites of all birds, similar to a finch except 50 times heavier, they can crack walnuts with difficulty, so they could perhaps get though a kid's finger.

Answer (score 0):

A word of warning. Ornithologically, cats and humans kill 1.3 billion wild birds indirectly, and 20 billion poultry. A seagull related heart attack happens every 20 years. [image]

this is a bite on a 1-year-old's finger, but from the news article, you would think she nearly died:
[image]

They can slice open a finger using the hook of their bill to snatch, there are 1-2 attacks per year in the UK. They have been know to attack pets.

A seagull attack can cause someone to fall off a pier or jump into the road head-first.

in 2007 a chef contracted cellulitis from a seagull cut, where all his arm was affected.

in 2002, an old man was cleaning the roof of his garage where he disturbed a nest of chicks, and he fell, was mobbed by the birds and suffered a heart attack.

Birds that can crack nuts like toucans and great macaws have a bite force of 10-20kg. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pUvg9Yis4Q

Seagulls don't really crack open snail and clam shells on the beach, to get into them, they must fly up and throw them onto some rocks. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWQqG6cwlBU

To break a finger bone you need 50-100 kg of force.

Seagulls have slender bills for pecking, impaling and hooking fish. Their bite force is unlikely to be above 5 kg, probably 2-3 kg.

A seagull is most dangerous to a human when it scares them from above and they jump into the street and land in an ungainly way, i.e. colliding with a car.

Out of the approximately 11,154 known bird species, 159 (1.4%) have become extinct, 226 (2%) are critically endangered, 461 (4.1%) are endangered, 800 (7.2%) are vulnerable and 1,018 (9.1%) are near threatened.